# Apple Airport Time Capsule with Airport express

Tags: wifi, airport, time-capsule

I've a apple airport express plugged and setup already and hooked onto it's WIFI.

Recently I bought Apple Time Capsule that comes with the router. I'm wondering what are my options.

1. Unplug the express and setup time capsule as the primary wifi
2. Extend the existing wifi (apple airport express) with this time capsule (not sure if possible) and use capsule as a backup for files only.

Is the router in the time capsule better than airport express?

Please note that I live in a studio so I don't have a range requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just give the Airport Express to someone who can make good use of it.

The Time Capsule is all you need, given that you don't need extended range.

Keeping your configuration simple will benefit you greatly compared to having two points of failure when something inevitably goes wrong.